# Segue in swift reload view

Tags: swift, swift2, segue, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I have one products page that shows products and also filter page. There is a button at the filter page and it has 2 conditions according the situation. According to filters I display different products from database.

I have one problem. If user go to filter screen and select nothing I should return same page with no load again my view.

If anything selected from the filter view this segue should reload my product screen and gets the correct data by using selected filters.

How can I set this button to segue with 2 different type?

Comment: Is your product and filter at different View?

Comment: Yes they are different Views.

Comment: Had you try NSNotificationCenter?

Answer (score 0):

You should define your own protocol let's name it `FilterSelector`.

```
protocol FilterSelector{
    func selectFilter(filter: String)
}
```

then in the `FiltersViewController` where user will select a filter you should define  a `delegate` let's name it `filterSelectorDelegate`

```
var filterSelectorDelegate: FilterSelector!
```

then in the products page you will implements `FilterSelector` protocol like this

```
extension ProductsViewController: FilterSelector{
     func selectFilter(filter: String){
        //Dismiss the filtersViewController 
        //and do what you want with the selected filter
     } 
}
```

Finally in Products page you should set the filterDelegate when you will present the filter page. And in filter page you will call `filterSelectorDelegate.selectFilter("selectedFilter")` when user select a filter.